# Lang Fiber Products

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

**STATEMENT:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.A product in $\mathcal{C}_z$ is called the fiber product of $f$ and $g$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and is denoted by $X\times_zY$, together with its natural morphisms on $X,Y$, over $Z$, which are sometimes not denoted by anything.

**QUESTION:** What is $X\times_zY$. Is it just the standard cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$  ?

Comment: No, it is the pullback in the category. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback

Comment: Alright. So essentially $X\times_zY$ is just a subset of the cartesian products of the two objects such that a given diagram,with $f,g$ commutes. Am I correct? I know its a little more detailed than that, but that is the essence of it right?

Comment: Yes, if you have equalizers and products then you can construct it as a subobject of the binary product $X \times Y$. For more details see the more general notion of limits  http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limit

Answer (score 0):

If $Z$ is a final object then the fibered product coincides with the usual product, however this is not true in general.

Note that the definition of the fibered product also includes ''projections'' $\pi_X: X\times_Z Y\to X$ and $\pi_X: X\times_Z Y\to  Y$, as well as two morphisms $\alpha:X\to Z$ and $\beta:Y\to Z$ such that $\alpha \circ \pi_X = \beta\circ \pi_Y$.  The fibered product is also required to be universal and is thus defined uniquely up to unique isomorphism using the standard construction.

In the category ***Set*** for example we have $X\times_Z Y = \{(x,y)\in X\times Y \,|\, \alpha(x)=\beta(y)\}$.

Just thought I should add that the fibered product needn't look like a restricted Cartesian product.  Consider the case of the category of open sets in a given topology where the morphisms are just the inclusion maps.  In this case the fibered product of two sets is their intersection.